# what is best way to for loop with large list(about use memory) in python2.6

Tags: list, for-loop, memory-management, garbage-collection, python-2.6

this is my memory profile results.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    88 1671.008 MiB    0.012 MiB           self.list_new_log = some_function()
    91 3769.992 MiB 2098.984 MiB           for i in self.list_new_log:
    92 3769.992 MiB    0.000 MiB               ...
                                               ...
                                               ...
   109   15.730 MiB -3754.262 MiB           release_memory(self.list_new_log)
```

**self.list_new_log** is splitlines() some file. (huge size list)

My problem is in line 91.

The for loop uses a lot of memory.

I have thought of a way to divide a huge list into several, but it does not seem to be a good way. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this.
http://tiborsimko.org/python-garbage-collection-issue.html
as a result, python2 gc has some bug.